# How can I decode the output off geth --trace?

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, geth-debugging

I've already gotten pretty acquainted with using the geth RPC commands to do block traces.

However, I am looking for a way to do this more directly. Hopefully without directly from geth, so I don't have to rely on scaling the RPC service.

I noticed that get has a debug option `--trace value` where value is a file. I was able to run this just fine. But here is where I need help. The file appears to be full of hex values, but I could only decode the first line. Here are the first 10 lines:

`676f 2031 2e39 2074 7261 6365 0000 0000
4100 8bc3 b988 834b 4500 078e ff2f 1401
6169 e0f0 c601 613b a0ad c701 5c24 1054
b606 1106 ad05 45f4 b001 078e ab32 1501
0f13 065e 45b6 a602 03dd 0409 0502 0066
0b05 5c96 011a 1e4f 0605 45b0 0207 063f
459a 8202 07dd 0916 0504 9991 c088 834b
660a 055c 201a 1e2a 0606 4577 038e 8331
1601 6131 b099 ce01 612c f0ae ce01 61f0
0590 d8ce 015c 3020 5ce9 0120 6192 01d0`

How is this log file encoded and what do I need to do to make use of the output here?